# 19.04 won't boot after installation

Tags: system-installation, 19.04

I installed 19.04 on a Windows 7 laptop after being prompted to restart, it just gave me a black screen with a cursor. It stayed like that for about 20 minutes before I turned it off and on again. Same thing. When I try to F12 and reinstall, it just freezes on the Dell screen. I loaded 18.04.2 on the USB stick to try and load an older version. When the computer turns on it goes to the Ubuntu purple screen with the five dots. It's been there for about an hour. What do I do?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is off-topic here as it's not released yet. For the problem with 18.04.2 installation, did you [verify the iso before making a bootable disk](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)?

Comment: When your 18.04.2 boots and you see keyboard-thing-in-rectangle & person-in-circle *quickly* press a key and you'll get a menu appear which offers the option to check-install-media.

Comment: If I can't prompt it to boot from USB, how do I know it's not still trying to run the 19.04?

Comment: As guiverc mentions, get to that menu, hit F6, and choose nomodeset, and it'll probably boot. That indicates a probable video/video driver issue which may be fixed after an install, or may require a minor tweak to disable Wayland.

Comment: My version of Ubuntu 19.04 is from April 18 and still does not boot after installation. I have on my 120GB HD a 60GB partition for Windows and two 30GB partitions for Ubuntu and of course another 4GB for SWAP. One Ubuntu partition holds Ubuntu 18.10. Into the other I tried tu install Ubuntu 19.04. I tried that three times, it came up with different problems. Once I was able to key in my password, but it stayed in a loop, asking me again and again for my password. In other cases the screen was scrambled.

Comment: So I thought, it might be a defect on the HD. Instead of 19.04 I installed a second version of 18.04. That installed flawlessly. So it can't be my HD, it must be a bug of Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Did you use any special options such as encryption or LVM? Did you format the disk manually?

Comment: I have tried to install Ubuntu 19.04 on three different Harddisks. They all stopped on a terminal screen saying:
[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
I was only able get a version on Ubuntu 19.04 to run, by installing Ubuntu 18.10 and then upgrading it to 19.04. Ubuntu 19.04 has a huge installation bug.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 19.04 via the installation command: Erase the whole disk and install Ubuntu 19.04. I dont't even know what encryption or LVM means. I just followed the instructions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

**I also have this problem in clean disk install, I resolve this problem reinstalling Ubuntu 19.04 without 3rd party drivers and that do the trick.**

> !!!Maybe
>   Related.

I also experience that if you disable auto login user for the system Ubuntu 19.04 won't load the graphics interfaces.

So, I had to restart press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> (in the loading Screen) and there you will see Ubuntu asking for user and password. And now write `startx` to start the graphic interface.

( I am almost new in Ubuntu so I don't know if this is a behavior by default or this is a bug ).

Answer (score 0):

My freshly installed Ubuntu 19.04 did not boot either. I used the program 'super-grub2-disk-hybrid_2.-20', burned on a CD-R, to boot Ubuntu 19.04. After booting Ubuntu the command 'grub-install' was used to write the boot manager.

Problem solved.

Regards,

NJB